# How to create a session in PHP with a randomized string?

Tags: php, session

How do I keep session state of a variable throughout a site?

For example:

A user lands on my website, the string generated is

```
$string = 'uejsh37rhda283jde86541as';
```

(This string is autogenerated by an xml feed on every page refresh).

Now, everything works so far ok. The problem is when the user clicks on another page on the site, the xml feed creates a new random string.

I know I have to use sessions here, but how exactly?

```
if(isset($_SESSION[])): 
     ?
else: 
      ?
endif;
```

**Updated code:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['session'])): 
      $string = $_SESSION['session'];
else: 
      $string = $sessionId;
      $_SESSION['session'] = $string;
endif;

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// call session_start() here if session handler is not started yet
if (isset($_SESSION['random-string'])) {
    $string = $_SESSION['random-string'];
} else {
    $string = generateRandomString();
    $_SESSION['random-string'] = $string;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you need to call session_start() on all pages that access or manipulate session data.

You can do it like this:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['string'])) {

  $string = makeString();
  $_SESSION['string'] = $string;

}
```

Comment: Very close, I'm getting somewhere. Can you see my updated code and point out where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Keith, can you explain what you are trying to do with the code? It appears as if you are trying to do what php does automatically for you. Have you looked at php's session_id()? Every session started by session_start() gets a unique identifier.

Comment: No probs codeburger. This is for a special feed. The feed creates a unique string used for each person accessing the site. It is vital that this string be used. So when the user visits other pages, the company who own the feed can track the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['my_string'])) {
    $string = $_SESSION['my_string'];
}
else {
    $string = generate_random_string();
    $_SESSION['my_string'] = $string;
}
// now do something with $string
```

Comment: Don't forget the `session_start()`